# How to identify to provide accurate information to other cyclists

Tags: discussion, identify-this-bike

Does anyone know a site I can send pictures of bicyles to help me identify them?

They are all 2017 to 2021 except a blue Battaglin frame. The ones I have in the US are a 2017 Willier,  Dacordi Carbon Sansone, Colnago Arabesque, & #62 Battaglin Limited Collezione and the Battaglin frame.